# How does StackExchange Redis client know which cluster node to call when using lua?

Tags: lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

If I understand it correctly, when calling something like `GET abc{def}ghi`, Redis client computes hash of `def`, modulo it by 16384 and then sends request directly to the cluster node responsible for handling this particular part of the space.

I wonder, how does this work in case of Lua scripts where it's not clear what keys it will work with? (I assume the script is going to be well-behaved and query only the keys from the same bucket.) What does a Redis client, particularly `StackExchange.Redis`, do in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending a key to the script, it will compute the hash slot on the key as usual and execute the script on the server that owns the hash slot.

When sending more than one key to the script, all should map to the same slot (or you will receive a `RedisCommandException`).
If you are not passing keys to the script, it will use a random server.

Marc Gravell can confirm if this is correct.